# RibbonToolTip is inheriting alignment from a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I'm having an issue with RibbonToolTips inheriting alignment from a textbox in the ribbon. The problem is that I can't seem to override this behavior no matter what I do. This only seems to manifest for Textboxes and Labels and RibbonTextBoxes seem to be unaffected.

XAML:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="RibbonToolTipTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Ribbon Title="WPF Ribbon" x:Name="Ribbon">
       <RibbonTab>
           <RibbonGroup Width="300">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="This is a test" TextAlignment="Right" x:Name="RegularLabel" />
                    <TextBox Width="200" TextAlignment="Left"  x:Name="RegularTextBox"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <RibbonTextBox Width="200"
                               ToolTipTitle="Title"
                               ToolTipDescription="The moon was shining sulkily, Because she thought the sun Had got no business to be there After the day was done — &quot;It's very rude of him,&quot; she said, &quot;To come and spoil the fun.&quot;" 
                               Label="Label" />
           </RibbonGroup>
       </RibbonTab>
   </Ribbon>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RibbonToolTipTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegularTextBox.ToolTip = RegularLabel.ToolTip = new RibbonToolTip()
            {
                Title = "Title",
                Description =
                    "The sun was shining on the sea, Shining with all his might: He did his very best to make The billows smooth and bright — And this was odd, because it was The middle of the night. ",
                HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying the `TextBlock.TextAlignment` property? You can find out more from the [TextBlock.TextAlignment Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

EDIT >>>

Sorry, I assumed that you could work out the rest. You could 'do that' if you used it in a `Style` in the `Resources` section:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

For users using .NET Frameworks older than .NET 4.5, you can download the `RibbonControlLibrary` dlls from Microsoft's [Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11877). Once installed, you can then add an XML namespace:

```
xmlns:Ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
```

And set up your style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon:RibbonToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

Comment: RibbonToolTip doesn't have that property, and Description is a string so I don't see how I would be able to do that.

Comment: This works beautifully, but I'm still not sure why. Is the style being a applied to a child-element of RibbonToolTip or is TextAlignment an attached property that doesn't show up on intellisense?

Comment: `TextAlignment` is a `Dependency Property` on the `TextBlock` class. According to the MSDN page that I added a link to, it is also an `Attached Property`, which enables us to apply it to controls that are not directly related. Setting this `Style` is a little bit like saying 'all child `TextBlock` controls in this control should set their `TextAlignment` properties to this value'.